# Requiring unreferenced assemblies to be included in Xamarin App package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app that requires me to dynamically load a single one of several possible assemblies at runtime (based on versioning). This should not be a problem as iOS can load assemblies using the mono interpreter. The problem I face is that the IPA and APK packages do not include the assemblies because they are not referenced directly in the app. I include them in the project references but they do not appear in the app package.

Is there a way to tell Xamarin to always include an assembly in the package regardless if it is being directly referenced in code?

==UPDATE==

I have a complete working POC with what I am trying to accomplish in terms of versioning in the application.
https://github.com/rlasker-b2w/XamVersioning

I specifically have to add references in the VersionSelector class otherwise the version projects do not get their assemblies added to the app package.
https://github.com/rlasker-b2w/XamVersioning/blob/main/VersionApp/VersionSelector.cs

Comment: I have provided an answer to a very similar question which I may think could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65144082/32348

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had looked at that but it didn't seem apparent how you can specify an entire assembly. Plus it curious because this is even in debug mode with the linker settings to "Don't Link" so it should not be running the linker yet still it does not include the assembly.

Comment: you are possibly battling with the compiler rather than the linker here then. It is likely optimising the reference out because you aren’t technically using it. I suspect if you did something like the last option (basically refer to something within the assembly to retain it then that might prove this case at least). I’d need to think on how you might achieve what you need. As for linking you may need to specify the assembly to not link which may not be in my answer but should be on the link to Microsoft’s site

Comment: Thanks again for your responses. I believe that you may be correct. Perhaps there is a way to tell the compiler to always include those projects. I will update the question to include a complete POC that shows what I am trying to do. In the POC I was forced to add references to each "version" project.

Comment: @webwires Anything update?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, nothing has changed. If we end up choosing this POC as the direction we go then we may need to revisit but for now having a hard reference was the only option.